# Can I Query Spring JPA @Query for any match of a list with another list?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I need to find matching entities where the parent entity has a list within it, I will pass in a list of Ids as a parameter and I want to match any parent entity where the inner list contains any of the parameter Ids, can this be done without a predicate approach?
Something along the lines of the following which I know wont work but would appreciate any pointers, have read http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/ and this scenario is not covered.

```
@Query("SELECT CASE WHERE COUNT (parent) > 0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END FROM Parent parent LEFT JOIN parent.children children where :ids in children")
boolean isFound(@Param("ids") List<Long> ids;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Spring JPA you can do something like :

```
@Repository
public interface ParentRepository extends CrudRepository<Parent, Long> {
    Boolean existsCountByChildrenIn(List<Integer> ids);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, I actually had to do an @Query as the logic is much more complex but it was the list within a list issue that was getting me.  Your answer however made me realise that I was over complicating it and when I do the left join on the children each child.id is a single id and I can happily do an "in :ids" for this.